# "Invalid argument" error when executing Perl on Windows 10

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl

I have this perl script.

```
perl -i -0pe 's/^Insert\s*(.*)\.png\s*\n([^\n]*)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/mg' */*.markdown
```

This works fine with MacOS X, but when I execute this command on Windows 10, I have the following error message:

```
C:\Users\hello\Desktop\progit\en>perl -i -0pe "s/^Insert\s*(.*)\.png\s*\n([^\n]*)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/mg"
*/*.markdown

Can't open */*.markdown: Invalid argument.
```

What might cause this issue on Windows 10? I use Strawberry Perl on Windows.

Comment: windows does not use '/', but '\' as a delimiter.
I remember it used to tolerate it at times, but that may be the issue. I don't have one to test this atm, though.
You might also want to check your regex for that same problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I tried the Perl [from MinGW](http://www.mingw.org), there is no error. The Cygwin based perl doesn't seem to have the problem (or bypass this problem).

Also refer to: [Multi-line regular expression issue in Perl on Windows 10.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337354/multi-line-regular-expression-issue-in-perl-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Strawberry issue.  It's a shell issue.  Bash will gladly expand multiple wildcards into long lists of command line parameters.  Microsoft's shells not so much.