# Multi-line regular expression issue in Perl on Windows 10.

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to convert this pattern in files

```
Insert 18333fig0101.png
Figure 1-1. Local version control diagram.
```

to

```
![Figure 1-1. Local version control diagram.](../figures/18333fig0101-tn.png)
```

This is the perl command:

```
perl -i -0pe 's/^Insert\s*(.*)\.png\s*\n([^\n]*)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/mg' */*.markdown
```

This works fine on Mac OS X, but it doesn't work on Windows 10.
I installed perl using `pacman -S perl` from `MSYS2`.

This is also not a `\r\n` issue as I checked there is no `\r` in the document.

Is this a known issue on Windows? Or, is there something different option needed for Windows?

Comment: Just because there aren't `\r`'s in the document, doesn't mean it's not an `\r\n` issue.

Comment: You say "it doesn't work", but what *does* happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the same command (after changing single quotes to double quotes), I get the following error message:

> Can't do inplace edit without backup.

This is documented in [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

> You're on a system such as MS-DOS that gets confused if you try
>   reading from a deleted (but still opened) file. You have to say `-i.bak`, or some such.

When I change the command to `perl -i.bak ...`, it works.

Comment: It was the double quote issue. I didn't have the backup issue.

Comment: Re "*I didn't have the backup issue*", Then you aren't using Windows. Maybe you're using cygwin build of Perl?